# "jboss-all.xml" with wildcards

Tags: xml, jboss, wildfly

I have a jboss-all.xml file set in my project to indicate that "moduleA-1.2.3.war" is dependent of "moduleB-4.5.6.war":

`<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="moduleB-4.5.6.war" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>`

It's working as expected in Wildfly 8.2 but the versions of modules A and B are constantly changing and I don't have control of these versions numbers to set the dependencies correctly in the file before the build of these modules.

Is it possible to use a wildcard to set the module's name (like "moduleB-*.war" or "moduleB-%.war")?

It there any other way to ignore the version numbers and still keeping the dependency?